# Причины закрытия - предложение добавить en.so в варианты более подходящих сайтов (только как причину закрытия, без миграции)

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Изменили заголовок, т.к. изначально имели ввиду дополнительную причину для закрытия вопросов на en. **Свободная миграция вопроса участниками не подразумевалась.**

---

Зачастую появляются [вопросы на английском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587447/191745), иногда их переводят, иногда минусуют, иногда закрывают.
Предлагаем добавить в причины закрытия в раздел более подходящих сайтов сайт stackoverflow.com, т.е.:

```
причина закрытия -> 
  не по теме -> 
    В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса -> 
      stackoverflow.com
```

А участникам в качестве причины закрытия в поле информации выводить следующий текст:

> Закрыт, так как на ru.stackoverflow.com вопросы принято задавать
>   только на русском языке. ru.stackoverflow.com is site for question and
>   answers on russian language only. Please translate your question in
>   russian language or ask your question on the [english version
>   stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Английский текст от некоторых пользователей](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/342/23044)

Comment: А много таких вопросов?  Ясно ли что комментариев, просящих перевести на русский не достаточно? Если добавление новой причины закрытия обосновано, то "Off-topic -> wrong language -> translate to reopen OR ask on enSO" вместо предложения о миграции вопроса (акцент должен быть на переводе, а enSO как ещё одна опция, если человек просто окошком ошибся).

Comment: @jfs если [so] в предложенном в вопросе варианте будет мигрировать вопрос, то однозначно нужно сделать новую причину в предлагаемом вами разделе, т.к. явно принудительно перенаправлять участника на другой сайт не является правильным решением. и комментариев не достаточно, зачастую переводят другие участники, а нужно чтобы это делал автор.

Comment: @jfs, вроде бы нельзя добавлять новую _стандартную_ причину типа _wrong language -> translate to reopen_ или имелось ввиду _другая -> напиши текст сам_?

Comment: @Grundy: я имел ввиду добавить подпункт в уже существующую причину (Off-topic), чтобы автору вменяемое сообщение о закрытие пришло ("отредактируйте вопрос и переведите на русский или на enSO его задайте"). Специальный комментарий позволил бы быстрее после перевода такие вопросы открывать. Текст этот следует читать в предположении (посмотрите на знаки вопросов в моём предыдущем комментарии): а) много таких вопросов б) комментариев недостаточно (из практики). Но похоже вопросов этих не так много, поэтому предположение ошибочно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Обновление 2**

Результатом стала новая причина закрытия вопроса в разделе «не по теме»:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

**Обновление**

Поскольку запрос функционала приобрел другой оттенок, убрал новый пункт описанный ниже.

---

Добавил дополнительный пункт меню в панель закрытия вопросов не по теме

```
Закрыть -> Не по теме -> В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса -> принадлежит stackoverflow.com
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого, модераторы могут перенести вопрос на любой сайт сети Stack Exchange.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы увидели вопрос, который необходимо перенести на другой сайт сети, пожалуйста, отметьте его сигналом тревоги, как требующего внимания модератора, указав, куда именно следует его перенести по вашему мнению.

Comment: а почему тогда на enSO, можно выбирать другие сайты сети не будучи модератором?

Comment: @Grundy Как я понимаю, вам доступно несколько предопределенных сайтов, верно? Или поле ввода для поиска нужного сайта есть?

Comment: да, предопределенный список: meta, superuser, tex, dba, stats. Не знаю по какому принципу он сформирован

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Попробую посмотреть в настройках сайта, возможно получится добавить.

Comment: @Grundy Обновил ответ.

Comment: кстати, а строка поиска только у модераторов получается?

Comment: @Grundy Ага, именно так.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я думаю не совсем правильно переносить вопрос, т.к. этим мы теряем возможного участника сообщества [ru.so] и его вопрос. На мой взгляд лучше именно **закрывать вопрос с указанной формулировкой** , т.к. этим мы сохраняем возможного участника(он сможет перевести вопрос и переоткрыть его) и выводим ему адекватную причину закрытия.

Comment: Возражаю против принятого решения. :) Приходите почитать аргументацию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, хорошо что тут диктатура а не демократия :P

Comment: Надо сделать текст причины закрытия двуязычным.

Comment: @PavelMayorov С одной стороны, да, согласен, с другой – не совсем. Как мне кажется, в русскоязычном сообществе, по возможности, должен быть лишь русскоязычный текст. Также, согласно моим субъективным наблюдениям, большенство вопросов на английском языке в русскоязычном сообществе публикуются русскоязычными участниками. Как минимум, их не смутил русскоязычный интерфейс сайта. Смею предполагать, что текст на английском языке в данном случае не нужен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky насчет русскоязычного интерфейса тут не всё очевидно, т.к. вопрос мог быть опубликован через приложение для мобильных устройств. А там интерфейс англоязычный. Но в общем случае, я тоже считаю, что пользователю надо быть внимательнее, и текст причины на английском не нужен. Скорее всего, процент пользователей, задающих вопрос по-английски на ruSO и при этом не знающих русский язык пренебрежимо мал.

Comment: @PavelMayorov обратите внимание на цитату в поле вопроса, предлагаемую в качестве информации о закрытии.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я думаю не совсем правильно дискриминировать ошибающихся англ. пользователей лишая их англ. текста в информации о закрытии, т.к. вопрос закрывается именно по причине "неправильного" языка и я думаю причина в закрытии должна быть понятна в т.ч. и автору без доп действий с его стороны.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я думаю, что стоит писать информацию на английском **только** в информационном поле причины закрытии (когда вопрос закрыт в желтом поле выводится причина закрытия и те, кто закрыл). Вот в этом поле и стоит указывать причину в т.ч. и на английском. А в модальном окне при выборе причины закрытия текст на анг. конечно будет лишним. Разумеется если это возможно.

Comment: @Alex На сколько я понимаю, описание как в поле выбора причины, так и в появляющейся фразе, одно и то же.

Answer (score 4):

Я обратил внимание на статистику, относящуюся к вопросам, перенесенным модераторами вручную на Stack Overflow на английском. Пожалуйста, учтите, модераторы переносят *только лучшие* вопросы, обычно, после внесения улучшающей правки, при необходимости.

Из 26 вопросов, которые были перенесены, 7% были закрыты на англоязычном сайте. Я думаю, что большинство вопросов [публикуемых на английском языке], которые вы видите, задаются участниками, получившими блокировку на публикацию вопросов в англоязычном сообществе по разным причинам.

Если мы добавим возможность переноса вопросов, то любой участник с более чем 3К репутации на Stack Overflow на русском будет иметь возможность перенести вопрос в англоязычное сообщество. Меня крайне беспокоит, что эти участники будут переносить все, что будет опубликовано на английском языке в русскоязычном сообществе, что позволит недобросовестным участникам обходить блокировку.

Как мне кажется, на данном этапе, в случае обнаружения хорошего вопроса на английском языке, лучшим подходом будет использование сигнала тревоги «требует внимания модератора».

---

I took a look at some statistics concerning the questions that have been migrated over to SOEN manually by the moderators. Please, remember - moderators are only sending the *best* of these questions over, usually after editing and improving them.

Of the 26 questions sent over so far, 7% have been rejected by the English site. I think quite a few of the English questions you're seeing are coming from people that have been blocked from asking questions on the English site due to chronic quality issues.

If we add a migration path, then anyone with 3k+ reputation here will be able to migrate questions to SOEN, and my worry is that people would just migrate anything in English, which would allow these users to get around their quality blocks.

I think for now the best idea is if you see a question in English that appears to be a good question, flag for moderator attention and let them know.

Comment: [I proposed](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4045/191745) to close the questions in English language on ru.stackoverflow.com and after some time migrate them to stackoverflow.com. **Only moderator should have an ability to migrate a question to SOen**. Users should not have rights to move questions (migration) without a moderator.

Comment: After a question was closed the moderators should decide whether to move the question or leave it closed on the site. I proposed to add only an adequate reason to teach users to ask questions in the right language and the right site.

Comment: @Alex there are custom close reasons available. It will take a few days for me to run numbers across all international sites, your idea is good, we just have to research the implementation a bit.

Comment: I think that the custom reasons aren't enough because any user can write the reason which can be unclear to the author. For example the author can not understand that he can ask a question on en.so. In this case the template is better because the reason from a template will be clear to both the author and other participants and it will contain information on possible actions of the author further.

Comment: If you afraid of migration of post published by blocked user - much better is to add a feature to migration algorithm which disable question migration if user is blocked on destination site.

Comment: hmm.. 7% from 26 ? ( it s 1.82 questions? not integer?) or there is typo somewhere?

Comment: @Batanichek try the other way around, 2.0 / 26 = 0.769[...], that looks about right.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит сразу же переносить вопрос на [en.so]. Этим мы потеряем вопрос и вероятнее всего потеряем потенциального участника сообщества [ru.so]. Поэтому лучше именно **закрывать** вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А участникам в качестве причины закрытия в поле информации следует выводить следующий текст:

> Закрыт, так как на ru.stackoverflow.com вопросы принято задавать
>   только на русском языке. ru.stackoverflow.com is site for question and
>   answers on russian language only. Please translate your question in
>   russian language or ask your question on the [english version
>   stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

P.S.: переносить вопрос лучше только в том случае, когда участник его не перевел и переоткрыл в течении года(например), т.е. когда можно точно сказать, что участник не заинтересован заниматься качеством своего вопроса. Если участник не заинтересован заниматься качеством своего вопроса за такой срок, то скорее всего он и на сайте не задержится.

Год - это пример. Можно вместо года брать месяц или несколько дней. Возможно даже, что перенос лучше делать через два дня, т.к. это позволит вопросу остаться *свежим* и после переноса.

Comment: `переносить вопрос лучше только в том случае, когда участник его не перевел и переоткрыл в течении года` - если автор не проявлял активности в течение последнего года, вероятность получить уточнения по вопросу крайне мала. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin судя по п.2 из Вашего ответа, реализация через робота становится невозможной.

Comment: @NickVolynkin т.к. `Перенос согласуется с модераторами этого сайта`, то переносить стоит, ведь вопрос будет задан на языке конечного сайта и **если он не так уж и плох(что решать будут модераторы), то** на него дадут ответ и хотя это скорее всего не будет нужно автору, **в базе SO будет еще один неплохой вопрос/ответ**. На мой взгляд пополнение базы Q/A SO не является плохим. А если модераторы конечного сайта SO посчитают вопрос некачественным, его можно просто оставить закрытым у нас.

Comment: Возможно мы можем добавить дополнительную причину закрытия в раздел не по теме. Проблема на мой взгляд в том, что автоматически такой вопрос не будет перенесен, а после закрытия про него все забудут.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky возможны несколько вариантов: 1 - если есть ответ, то участник скорее всего переведет и вопрос(мне кажется, что и найдутся участники, которые будут просто переводить вопрос и переоткрывать его). 2 - если вопрос имеет рейтинг 0, то можно поставить минус и робот удалит его сам через некоторое время(не заминусовать вопрос, а именно поставить 1 скромный минус, т.е. чтобы у вопроса был рейтинг -1 если конечно он не совсем плох).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky из комментария выше следует убрать 2-е решение с минусом, т.к. у *Духа* [достаточно причин](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) по которым он может удалить некачественный вопрос со временем. Т.е. если вопрос на en останется закрытым на [ru.so], то на него со временем найдется ответ или *Дух* скорее всего удалит вопрос по [какой-то из причин](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: Теоретически, это отличные решения. На практике – не известно. Не так давно автор одного из переведенных вопросов написал в поддержку с требованием «перевести обратно» и отправить на англоязычный сайт. Сообществу практически не возможно понять, ошибся ли автор языком или сайтом. Как мне кажется, в этом случае, всегда лучше переносить вопросы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky поэтому лучше закрывать с понятной причиной, а через пару дней(или иной срок) переносить вопрос, если автор не удосужился перевести его. Нужно дать участнику после закрытия вопроса время подумать о принятии решения(перевести или задать вопрос на en.so). Так у него не возникнет негатива к действиям общества.

Comment: С большой вероятностью, через пару дней мы все забудем про такой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя просто переносить любой заданный на английском языке вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском:

- этот вопрос может быть попросту плохим и его там сразу закроют;
- вопрос может быть офф-топиком для en.SO, но подходящим для другого сайта сети;
- с немалой вероятностью автор знает русский язык и сможет перевести вопрос ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586843/181472)).

Поэтому последовательность действий должна быть такой:

1. Выяснить, понимает ли автор русский язык и может ли перевести вопрос.
2. Если нет, через модераторов инициировать перенос вопроса. В таких случаях мы обсуждаем вопрос в общем чате модераторов всей сети и находим наиболее подходящий сайт. Перенос согласуется с модераторами этого сайта. Если такого сайта нет или он есть, но вопрос там сразу закроют, то обычно вопрос просто не переносится и остаётся в закрытом виде здесь.

Не нужно рассматривать enSO как свалку для любого текста, написанного латиницей.

Предлагаю удалить эту причину закрытия.

Comment: я изначально не подумал, что это приведет к миграции. поэтому я и [**предлагаю**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4045/191745) именно закрывать его, а не переносить.

Comment: _этот вопрос может быть попросту плохим и его там сразу закроют;_ - так его и тут закроют. _вопрос может быть офф-топиком для en.SO, но подходящим для другого сайта сети;_ - так стоит добавить наиболее частые сайты еще. _с немалой вероятностью автор знает русский язык и сможет перевести вопрос_ - так может он и хотел задать на английском, просто сайты перепутал???