# Новая причина закрытия для вопросов, заданных на английском языке

Tags: поддержка

С ростом популярности нашего сообщества в нем все чаще публикуются вопросы на английском языке (скорее всего, многие разработчики не понимают разницу между *Stack Overflow на русском* и *Stack Overflow на английском*, либо просто не знают о существовании первого). Как результат, спасибо [инициативе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4039/) участника [@Alex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191745/alex), появилась новая причина закрытия вопросов «не по теме»:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

[image: Новая причина закрытия вопроса]

Пожалуйста, используйте ее если видите вопрос, заданный на английском языке. *Если такой вопрос отвечает стандартам Stack Exchange, пожалуйста, отметьте его тревогой, как требующего внимания модератора.* Модератор перенесет вопрос в англоязычное сообщество вручную, в случае, если автор хотел опубликовать его именно на *Stack Overflow на английском*, но что–то пошло не так.

Comment: Причина же совершенно непонятна не-русскоговорящим. Нужен текст на английском!

Comment: не знал, что можно выделить текст курсивом при помощи нижнего подчеркивания..

Comment: @Alex одно _ или * - получается _курсив_, два - __полужирный__. Это часть [спецификации Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Согласно моим субъективным наблюдениям, практически все авторы таких вопросов прекрасно понимают русский язык.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как проверялось? Согласно моим наблюдениям, еще ни один автор не перевел вопрос на русский язык сам...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Проверялось через отзывы. Люди пишут на простом русском языке, протестуя, что их вопрос был переведен, так как они хотели опубликовать его в англоязычном сообществе. Таким образом, проблема не в англоязычной формулировке, а в непонимании работы системы (в наличии разных сообществ). Если допустить, что большенство задают свой вопрос через сайт, то как минимум авторов вопросов не смутил интерфейс сайта на русском языке. Проверяется просто попробуйте задать вопрос [тут](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/). Уверен, вы быстро поймете, что что–то идет не так.

Comment: касательно причины закрытия только на русском: ***за*** - **1** мои наблюдения совпадают с мнением @NicolasChabanovsky , **2** - как мне кажется участник, вопрос которого закрыли, если не знает русский, то пойдет смотреть перевод причины закрытия.
***против*** - **1** лишние действия для участника, я за то, чтобы было меньше действий для участника, но сейчас 2016 год, пусть учат русский :) Лично я бы скорее голосовал за добавление текста на английском (несмотря на 2016 год).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хм, а ссылка на протесты есть? Или они тревоги кидали с протестами? Почему-то я ни одного протеста против перевода не видел, теперь думаю как так могло получиться...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ссылки нет. Все в ZenDesk. Протесты отправляли через форму обратной связи (опять же на нашем сайте, а не на англоязычном, что тоже на так просто, так как надо еще ее найти в подвале и выбрать правильную формулировку). .

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Кажется, я понял. Если вбить в гугл "stackoverflow support" - первая же ссылка ведет на нужную страницу. А вот просто "stackoverflow" ведет на ru.SO

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в яндекс - на enSO

Comment: @PavelMayorov так это же поиск с учетом истории запросов пользователя. У меня например, что гугл, что яндекс отображают ссылку на enSO.

Comment: @alexolut там еще регион учитывается

Comment: @PavelMayorov тем более.