# Добавить возможность предлагать другие сайты, помимо Меты ruSO, при голосовании для закрытия вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Сейчас пока так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какие вы предлагаете? Вроде других и нету.

Comment: @0xdb да хоть бы русский язык, например, а вообще и на другие было было неплохо разрешать отправлять.

Comment: Самое смешное, нет сайта по русскому языку на русском в сети SE. Есть [англоязычный](https://russian.stackexchange.com/). И что туда тогда можно было бы перенести? Пару примеров - "так ни в коем случае не надо писать"?

Comment: @0xdb https://rus.stackexchange.com/ не вижу повода для смеха.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а может не дубликат, с учётом комментариев? Т. е. как предложение добавить два русских сайта?

Comment: @Qwertiy проблема в доступах - я раньше предлагал сделать это, но возникла ситуация, что любой смог переносить (сейчас если не ошибаюсь все модераторы могут или один Николас, точно не помню), поэтому перебил заголовок на причину закрытия. По-хорошему нужно делать такой же функционал как и удаление вопроса и отображать функционал по голосованию за перенос только пользователям с большой репутацией. Но это все равно не решает проблему ошибочного переноса, а модераторы иного ресурса не обрадуются таким "подаркам".

Comment: @Alex, так там и есть голосование, вроде? В любом случае, на enSO же перенос на другие сайты работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2GM.png. Понятно, что на англоязычные сайты предлагать перенос не стоит, но уж из трёх русских, думаю, пользователи разберутся?

Comment: @Qwertiy к сожалению не хватает репутации, чтоб увидеть, времени еле еле хватает на ru.so) Судя по скриншоту да, голосование. Но лично я против, чтобы пользователи с меньше чем 10k могли голосовать за перенос, т.к. я солидарен с [мнением TimPost](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4051/191745) по данному вопросу и голосование за перенос это более ответственное дело чем закрытие вопроса в своем сообществе. P.S.: несмотря на то, что у меня меньше 10k :) P.P.S: если голосование за перенос вопросов на en.so успешно внедрено, то его стоит перенести к нам(внедрить), только увеличить лимиты.

Comment: @Alex, перенос работает как обычное закрытие, не думаю, что репутацию там можно настроить. Но он работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy я думаю, что данный вопрос стоит обговорить нашим модераторам с Николасом и другими модераторами на en.so, а также с теми к которым хотелось бы переносить вопросы. *...не думаю, что репутацию там можно настроить* - если это работает как закрытие, то у нас нужно будет всего 3000 для переноса. Возможно стоит запустить пока на время и посмотреть будут ли ошибочные переносы, а для лучшего контроля, например, сделать отдельный чат для ссылок на вопросы для переноса, чтобы модераторы и неравнодушные участники могли быстро отслеживать начавшееся голосование за перенос.